# Ubuntu One Windows Client 3.0.1 - Sync not connecting

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows, proxy

I've got sync working at home on Natty and I need to access files at work. I've just installed client 3.0.1 at work on Windows 7. It's finding my account and sees what devices are already set up for sync but it just repeatedly tries to sync (File sync starting...) and after a while fails (File Sync is disconnected.). This cycle loops endlessly.

I'm suspicious that it's a problem with my proxy setup. My employer doesn't use a manual proxy configuration but instead uses an automatic configuration script at a specific http address.

Does U1 recognize that kind of setup or is it only looking for a proxy server in the form of an address/port?

Answer (score 1):

we found a big bug in the windows proxy support and we are planning on a release for next week to fix it.

Comment: How's this coming along?

Comment: We are doing the build today, signing, QA, it may take a couple of days more. If you are desperate, drop by #ubuntuone on freenode, I can give you a test build :-)

Comment: bump. What's the latest?